# Construct two lists from a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries with 2 or more keys, and I want to construct 2 or more lists based on those keys. For example:

```
dict_list = [{'key1':1, 'key2':2}, {'key1': 3, 'key2':4}, ... ]
```

should become

```
list1 = [1, 3, ...]
list2 = [2, 4, ...]
```

To construct a single list, there's the elegant solution:

```
list1 = [item['key1'] for item in dict_list]
```

However, doing this twice would be inefficient. Is there an efficient and elegant or Pythonic way of doing this? The other solution I have is something like:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
for item in dict_list:
    list1.append(item['key1'])
    list2.append(item['key2'])
```

but, of course, this feels less elegant than some sort of list comprehension technique.

Comment: "However, doing this twice would be inefficient" - no, not really. I quite recommend it.

Comment: No, it really would be inefficient. Perhaps "twice" is not, but if I have `n` keys I'm interested in, it would take `n` loops, which is not desirable.

Comment: It'd take 2 loops, because you'd just nest them. `[[d[key] for d in dict_list] for key in key_list]`. In terms of computational time, it'd be asymptotically optimal, too. You can't do better than `O(len(dict_list)*len(key_list))`, since that's the size of the output.

Comment: I think OP means it would be inefficient to _type it out_ for every single `list` and key.

Comment: Given the optimizations that go into list comprehensions, while it may seem inefficient, doing the list comp twice might actually be a lot faster than writing a for loop.  Have you tried timing it?

Comment: Asymptotically it's all O(n), or O(kn) where k is the number of keys and n the number of dicts.  You either do k steps per loop, with n loops, or you do n loops of 1 dict lookup each, k number of times.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend making a single dictionary with keys like the original dictionaries and values of `list`s containing each of the original dictionaries' appropriate values:

```
>>> dict_list = [{'key1':1, 'key2':2}, {'key1': 3, 'key2':4}]
>>> dct = {}
>>> for d in dict_list:
...     for k in d:
...         dct.setdefault(k, []).append(d[k])
...
>>> dct
{'key1': [1, 3], 'key2': [2, 4]}
```

Comment: This also has a downside. Now, how will OP know which is the first list?

Comment: He can use an `OrderedDict` if he cares about the order. I didn't include it because he didn't mention it, and it didn't seem necessary.

Comment: FWIW there is nothing wrong with having a predefined set of keys, itemgetter and zip.

Comment: Nothing at all, until the dictionaries change.

Comment: I think this method creates a bunch of possibly unnecessary operations. For example, if there were 20 keys in the dictionary, but I was only interested in 3 of them, it would construct 17 lists that I would never access. Is there any other approach?

Comment: @Teofrostus - if you only want certain ones (which was not mentioned in your question), you can easily take care of that with a simple `if k in my_keys:` after the `for k in d:`.